# Looker CSP issue: Unable to load looker reports in iframe

Tags: angular, content-security-policy, looker

I am using an iframe to load the looker dashboard in our angular application but getting the below error.

Refused to frame 'https://looker.lab.redseal.net:9999/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'frame-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 0):

Your application publishes default Content Security Policy with `default-src 'self'` rule (only resources from site's own domain are allowed). Therefore `https://looker.lab.redseal.net:9999/` is not allowed.
I can guess this is trick of [Helmet middleware](https://helmetjs.github.io/#reference), v4 switches default CSP On, while v3 - does not.

You can modify CSP to `default-src 'self'; frame-src https://looker.lab.redseal.net:9999;` to allow this iframe. See the `helmet.contentSecurityPolicy(options)` for details.

Or you can disable CSP at all (this reduced security).